# Dropdown onclick server side

Tags: c#

I have a dropdown defined within a nav-bar (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-dropdowns) and I want to, when I click on the dropdown a function on server side to be executed.

My dropdown:

```
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
    <a href="../#" id="notS" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell" aria-hidden="true"><span id="not" class="badge">3</span></span>
     </a>
      <ul id="notificacoes" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li role="presentation">
              <a runat="server" onserverclick="setVisivel" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="../Admin/VerRevisoes?id=1144">
              As revisões do caso 1144 estão completas
              </a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation">
              <a runat="server" onserverclick="setVisivel" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="../Admin/VerRevisao?id=7">
              Foi adicionada uma nova revisão ao caso 1144
              </a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation">
              <a runat="server" onserverclick="setVisivel" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="../Admin/Casos">
              O caso 1145 foi adicionado pelo utilizador 1
              </a>
          </li>
     </ul>
 </li>
```

And my funtion setVisivel it C# and it's on server side:

```
protected void setVisivel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBConFactory.getInstance().setVisibleNotificacao(int.Parse(Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()));
    }
```

But when I click the dropdown, the function setVisivel is not called!

Comment: I don't see a question or a problem described. What is the behavior you're seeing? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: I forgot! Already edited!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have set the property of ASP.NET DropDown control: `AutoPostBack="True"` (like explained in MSDN online:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx )

Working example, the DropDownList is declared as:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbSelectChannel" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

Hope this may help. Best regards,

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET control, then put it inside that DropDown list tag. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion; try to integrate two different technologies .NET and bootstrap in a way others have tried before.

try to read this:
http://techbrij.com/responsive-menu-twitter-bootstrap-asp-net

then modify your bootstrap CSS and make it look like what your dropdown looks like now.